# Sort ArrayList of custom object and reorder in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I have a ArrayList of CustomObject, my object is simply made of two values x and y

```
MyObject = (double)x && (double)y
```

What I want to do is:

1. remove duplicate from array : simply remove duplicate object and if the objects have the same x keep the one if the higher y.
2. reorder the list depending on the x value (x is for the time, y is a factor)

I have tried using `Collections.sort` to reorder my array and using a set to remove duplicate but nothing works.

```
Collections.sort(listPoints, new Comparator<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject lhs, MyObject rhs) {
        return Double.compare(lhs.y, rhs.y);  
    }
});

Collections.sort(listPoints, new Comparator< MyObject >(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject lhs, MyObject rhs) {
        return Double.compare(lhs.x, rhs.x);  
    }
});
```

Comment: What is a custom object?

Answer (score 2):

Sorting a list twice with different comparators will not work. You need to compare both x and y in the same comparator.

```
public int compare(MyObject lhs, MyObject rhs) {
    int result = Double.compare(lhs.y, rhs.y);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    return Double.compare(lhs.x, rhs.x);
}
```

Using a set to remove duplicates will work if MyObject correctly implements the equals() and hashCode() methods.

Comment: What do you mean by `The sorting implemented by Collections.sort() is not stable`?

Comment: Actually please disregard that. Collections.sort() does do a stable sort, but it's irrelevant here.

Comment: than you i'll give a try

Answer (score 0):

For getting unique elements for your custom class you can just add all elements to something like `HashSet`. For using this you need to override the `Object#hashCode()` method to let it return the same `hashCode()` value `x` and `y` of `MyObject` instance. Don't forget to override `Object#equals()` as well.

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) for more on overriding `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: thai you i'll give a try

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Comparable<MyObject>` in MyObject class and then use `TreeSet<MyObject>`, as result you have sorted unique values.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates and keep the sorted order, i would suggest the following:

- You store the Objects of type MyObject in a List
- Sort them as you are doing with x field
- iterate over the list and check for duplicates with previous elements (implements equals and hashCode methods in MyObject class) and remove one with less value in 'y' field.